# Discrete sets is enumerable

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that every non-enumerable set has accumulation point.

Using the contrapositiva we have

If it does not have accumulation point then the set is discrete, thus enumerable.

Proof: Be $I$ a discrete set, we take ${I}_{x}$ e ${I}_{y}$ intervals centered on x and y such that ${I}_{x}\cap{I}_{y}=\emptyset$.
Let $A=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} {I}_{j}$ the union of the two to two distinct enumerable intervals.
As $I\subset A $ then $I$ is enumerable.

$A=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} {I}_{j}$ Is it enumerable or not? I could not answer that question

Comment: The OP assumedly means (from his tag line "real-analysis") that the universe is the real line with the usual topology. If the universe is $R^\infty$ with the box topology then I don't think the statement is true.

Comment: A union of real intervals is *never* enumerable, because just a single interval is in bijection with $\Bbb R$. Moreover, the definition of "discrete set" gives you for each point $x\in I$ an interval $I_x$ such that, for all $y\in I$, $y\notin I_x$, but it does not guarantee that $x\ne y\implies I_x\cap I_y=\emptyset$

Comment: First, you define $I_x$ as an interval centered at $x$ and then you define $A$ as the union of $I_j$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$. What is $I_j$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $ {I}_{j}= \{{{I}_{1},......,{I}_{n},..}\}$ Such that ${I}_{x} \subset {I}_{j}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is confusing. First you say you're going to use contrapositive then you start of with a discrete set (which is the consequence of the contrapositive) you should then start with the contrapositive premise.

A direct proof can be constructed as:

What you do is assume that $X$ is non-enumerable. Now consider $I_n = [n,n+1]$ and let $X_n = X\cap I_n$. Now we have $X = \bigcup X_n$ and if all $X_n$ are finite then $X$ would be enumerable.

So what we have to prove is that if a bounded set is infinite it has an accumulation point. This can be proven in different ways, for example using interval halfing. We note that if we split the interval in half either of the parts will contain infinite number of points. This way we confine non-empty (actually infinite) subset into a ever shrinking region. This will construct an accumulation pont.

---

If you insist on using the contrapositive the approach is similar in that we divide the real line into unit intervals $I_j$. What we do in each unit interval is that we cover it with open sets as follows: Since there are no accumulation points we have that for each point $c$ there's an open set around it that intersects $X$ no where except possibly at $c$. This way we can cover $I$ with open sets - one for each point in $I$. Since $I$ is compact we have a finite subcover, that is a finite collection of sets that each contains at most one element in $X$. This means that $I_j\cap X$ is finite. This means that $X=\bigcup X_j$ is enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Fischler said that space and topology are important. Assuming $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.

We'd like to prove:

$$
A\text{ has no accumulation points}\Rightarrow A \text{ is countable}.
$$
Define $I_n:=[-n,n]$ and $A_n=I_n\cap A$.

**Claim:** $A_n$ contains finite many elements.

*Proof:* Suppose $A_n$ has inifinite many points, then there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n\subset A_n\subset I_n$. Since $I_n$ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}\to x\in I_n$. But this would be an accumulation point of $A$ such that we get a contradiction and the claim holds.

Finally, we get
$$
A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n.
$$
Since all $A_n$ are finite, $A$ is countable as countable union of countable sets.